# What do they say in The Revenant?

Tags: dialogue, the-revenant

I am not a native English speaker. So I have some problems about strange dialogues.
What does Fitzgerald mean in this line in *The Revenant*?

> Fitzgerald: If we keep it, we can lay it up around hours peak.
>
> Another Man: Quit acting like you know what you're talking about, Fitzgerald.

Did Fitzgerald want to say that "they will hide upon peak mountain"?

Comment: Do you have a timestamp we can use to have a quick listen?

Comment: This scene is from 00:15:15 to 00:15:19. But I do not have a video clip.

Comment: "We can lay it up around Arrow's Peak." but without watching the rest of it I can't remember what, if any, significance that has

Comment: Also please turn on closed captions when watching this movie, there are many other dialogs where you'll get lost (and there's the natives dialogues too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual quote is

> We keep it, we can lay it up around Arrow's Peak.

### Arrow's Peak is a place.

They are talking about the idea of leaving the boat behind and moving inland.

"[Lay it up](https://www.sailingtoday.co.uk/cruising/cruising-stories/laying-up-tricks-of-the-trade/)" refers to pulling the boat out of the water and protecting it against the elements or discovery for later use.